# legs function in the Mapping toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, mapping

Can anyone tell me if the legs function in the Mapping toolbox in Matlab specifies the shape of the Earth using ellipsoid or sphere?

I am using the legs function to find the GCD between two points on the earth, using a function like this:

```
[course, distgcd] = legs(lat, lon, 'gc')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the 'gc' argument, this function computes the distance on the sphere. If you want to compute the distance on the ellipsoid (which obviously will be more accurate) use the [distance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/distance.html) function.